# Регулярное выражение вида "Maxim_Ivanov"

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, winforms

1-ый раз работаю с регулярными выражениями.

Есть регулярка: `([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}_([A-Z]{1,1})[a-z]{2,9}`

Как сделать, чтобы заглавные буквы были только: **1-ая буква** в строке и **1-ая** после `_` ?

Сейчас срабатывает на **MaXim_Ivanov**, нужно только чтобы срабатывало на **Maxim_Ivanov**

Comment: А текст произвольный или что там?

Comment: @Сергей, да, произвольный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+_[A-Z][a-z]+$
```

`{1,1}` - не нужно

`^` - начало строки

`$` - конец строки

`+` - 1 или больше символов

Тест:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/j8b

Comment: А если посреди строки?

Comment: @Сергей как я понял, это не нужно

Comment: Текст произвольный, ну да ладно) Ответ принят

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно добавить символ границы слова

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}_[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}
```